# ath9k loaded but wlan0 is not there

Tags: wifi

I have an old Fedora-3 installation on a desktop. Recently put in a TL-W851ND wireless card on one of the remaining PCI slots. I also compiled kernel 2.6.20.27 which has the driver for the card. `lsmod | grep ath` shows `ath9k mac80211` yet `iwconfig wlan0` complains that there is no `wlan0` device.

The only reference in `dmesg` is: `ath9k: 0.1`

```
lspci | grep Ath" shows 01:07.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications, Inc.: Unknown device 002d (rev 01)
```

Please, not that Fedora-3 is my sandbox where I play and learn Linux intricacies. The same desktop can boot into xUbuntu 14.04 and then wireless works.

Any ideas why there is no device when I boot into kernel 2.6.20.27?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that kernel 2.6.20.27 has the ath9k module but the module doesn't support the 002D device.  (X)Ubuntu 14.04 uses the 3.13 kernel

You may be able to check with `modinfo ath9k`
If it supports your wireless you should have a line that shows

```
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Dsvsdbcsci*
```

https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN851ND shows that this device was first supported in Linux with kernel 2.6.32